# VBA - Populate cell if adjacent cell is not empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros

I have created a macro that opens and edits excel workbooks for me.

Firstly, it adds a new column A and then changes the title for A1, B1, C1, D1.

After this, I want to create some sort of formula / a loop in VBA that adds in a piece of text (31/12/2014) in this case to each cell in A but only if there is text in the adjacent cell to the right RC[1].

Does anybody have an idea as to how I should edit the indicated code of my VBA to carry this through?

Not as important but I would like that date to be changed through my excel sheet. Is there an easy way of doing that as when I did it using Range("E7").Value (and edited E7). The formatting was out in all of my other workbooks.

```
Sub test()


Dim MyPath          As String
Dim MyFile          As String
Dim Wkb             As Workbook
Dim Cnt             As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'MyPath = "G:\SHARED\Style Research\Portfolios - Macro Test"
MyPath = Range("D6").Value

If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls")

Cnt = 0
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    Cnt = Cnt + 1
    Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFile)
    Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert

'this is the part I'm referring to
    Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A250") = "31/12/2014"
    'Range("D7").Value

    'Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
    Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "Date"
    Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = "Identifier"
    Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1") = "Name"
    Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1") = "%"

    Wkb.Close savechanges:=True
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

If Cnt > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Completed...", vbExclamation
Else
    MsgBox "No files were found!", vbExclamation
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple, use a `for loop` with an `if` condition like this -

```
Sub test()
For Each c In Range("A:A")
 If c <> 0 And c.Offset(, 1) <> 0 Then
     c.Value = 1
 End If
Next
End Sub
```

You can change the range to fit your data, or you can try to get the `usedrange`. I don't quite understand your second part.